# Find Link that matches search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a search box and on the same page I have a list of links

If I type in the search box.. "Test1".. then I should be returned with that link.. if I type in.. "Te".. then I should be returned all of the links.

I have read about using `.filter` but not sure how to implement it.

```js
$("#ButtonSearch").click(function() {
  var textboxValue = $("#SearchLink").val();
  $("a").each(function() {
    // here is where I am stuck.. how do I compare textboxValue to each of the link's text and return a match?
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="SearchLink" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="ButtonSearch" />

<h4><a href="#" id="Trig5">General Information</a></h4>
<div class="slider" id="Slide5">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="www.test1.com" target="_blank">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test2.com" target="_blank">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test3.com" target="_blank">Test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test4.com" target="_blank">Test4</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test5.com" target="_blank">Test5</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test6.com" target="_blank">Test6</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test7.com" target="_blank">Test7</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test8.com" target="_blank">Test8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hint: normalize the case of both value and href (or text) to compare

Comment: use innerHTML string to compare

Comment: try my code for search with any keyword like only with number or any character which have in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `indexOf` method. You have to `iterate` all `hyperlink` elements using `each` function and show only those that contain `textboxValue`.

```js
$("#ButtonSearch").click(function(){

    var textboxValue = $("#SearchLink").val();
    $('.slider').each(function(){
       var exist=false;
       $(this).find('ul li').each(function(){
         if($(this).find('a').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textboxValue.toLowerCase())!=-1){
          $(this).show();
          exist=true;
        }
        else
           $(this).hide();
       });
       if(exist==false){
          $(this).prev('h4').hide();
       }
      else{
          $(this).prev('h4').show();
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="SearchLink" />
<button type="button" id="ButtonSearch">Click</button>
<h4><a href="#" id="Trig5">General Information</a></h4>
    <div class="slider" id="Slide5">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="www.test1.com" target="_blank">Test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test2.com" target="_blank">Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test3.com" target="_blank">Test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test4.com" target="_blank">Test4</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test5.com" target="_blank">Test5</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test6.com" target="_blank">Test6</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test7.com" target="_blank">Test7</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test8.com" target="_blank">Test8</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h4><a href="#" id="Trig6">General Information2</a></h4>
    <div class="slider" id="Slide6">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="www.test1.com" target="_blank">Test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test2.com" target="_blank">Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test3.com" target="_blank">Test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test4.com" target="_blank">Test4</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test5.com" target="_blank">Test5</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test6.com" target="_blank">Test6</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.test7.com" target="_blank">Test7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: anyway that when the textbox is blank to return all links?

Comment: If i type in "Test1" I am given the correct elements.. but then when I delete "Test1" from the textbox and hit search.. it just keeps the elements that I searched for with "Test1".. it doesn't 'refresh' the page

Comment: Just FYI you could get rid of the `if` statement and just use `$(this).prev('h4').toggle(exist)`

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use the `filter()` method to return only the elements which contain the textual value you're searching for.

To preform a case-insensitive comparison you can simply convert both the element's text and the value you're searching for to the same case, in the example below I made them both lower case.

Also, presumably you want to hide the entire `li` element, not just the `a`, if the text is not found so I amended the selector used. Try this:

```js
$("#ButtonSearch").click(function() {
  var textboxValue = $("#SearchLink").val().toLowerCase();

  if (textboxValue) {
    $("li").hide().filter(function() {
       return $(this).find('a').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textboxValue) != -1;
    }).show();
  } else {
    $('li').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="SearchLink" />
<button id="ButtonSearch">Search</button>

<h4><a href="#" id="Trig5">General Information</a></h4>
<div class="slider" id="Slide5">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="www.test1.com" target="_blank">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test2.com" target="_blank">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test3.com" target="_blank">Test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test4.com" target="_blank">Test4</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test5.com" target="_blank">Test5</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test6.com" target="_blank">Test6</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test7.com" target="_blank">Test7</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test8.com" target="_blank">Test8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that this will also show all the `li` elements again if no value is entered in the box. It will also search for a match anywhere within the text of the `a` element. If you specifically only want to find a match at the beginning of the text, replace `!= -1` with `== 0`.

Comment: This works.  I just have 1 more thing.. As you can see, my links are under a `h4` element (there are multiple other sections like you see above, on my page).. and the only way to see the links is to click on the heading... so the only problem with what you have provided is, is that all of the heading's are still there, but only the headings that contain the links that match the search box value have links under them.. is there a way to hide the `h4` elements that don't contain a link underneath of them that matches the searchbox?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, i do this functionality in my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#SearchLink").keyup(function() {
  var keyid = $("#SearchLink").val().toLowerCase();
 
    var filter = keyid; 
    count = 0;
   // console.log(filter);
        // Loop through the comment list
        $(".search_area li").each(function(){
 
            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
 
            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="SearchLink" />


<h4><a href="#" id="Trig5">General Information</a></h4>
<div class="slider" id="Slide5">
  <ul class="search_area">
    <li><a href="www.test1.com" target="_blank">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test2.com" target="_blank">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test3.com" target="_blank">Test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test4.com" target="_blank">Test4</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test5.com" target="_blank">Test5</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test6.com" target="_blank">Test6</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test7.com" target="_blank">Test7</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test8.com" target="_blank">Test8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this code with live search without search button

Answer (score 0):

First, lowercase both the hrefs and the value of the input. Second use `indexOf` to see if an href contains the value like this:

```
var textboxValue = $("#SearchLink").val().toLowerCase();

$("a").each(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase();
   if(href.indexOf(textboxValue) !== -1) {
       // matched
   } else {
       // not matched
   }
})
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
$("#SearchLink").on("input", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase();
    if (href.indexOf(value) !== -1)
      $(this).css("background", "red");
    else
      $(this).css("background", "white");
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="SearchLink" />
<h4><a href="#" id="Trig5">General Information</a></h4>
<div class="slider" id="Slide5">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="www.test1.com" target="_blank">Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.test2.com" target="_blank">Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.test3.com" target="_blank">Test3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.test4.com" target="_blank">Test4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.test5.com" target="_blank">Test5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.test6.com" target="_blank">Test6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.test7.com" target="_blank">Test7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.test8.com" target="_blank">Test8</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily and you are too near of your code.

Just try this :

```
$("li a").each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    if(link.search(textboxvalue)){
         // Here Place code if keyword match
    }else{
        //Here you can hide mismatch link. . . 
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

2 versions. One for the href, one for the text

```js
$("#ButtonSearch").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var textboxValue = $("#SearchLink").val().toLowerCase();
/*  $("#Slide5 li").each(function() { 
    $(this).toggle($("a[href*=" + textboxValue + "]",this).length>0); 
  });*/
  $("#Slide5 li a").each(function() { 
    $(this).closest("li").toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textboxValue) !=-1);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="SearchLink" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="ButtonSearch" />
<h4><a href="#" id="Trig5">General Information</a></h4>
<div class="slider" id="Slide5">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="www.test1.com" target="_blank">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test2.com" target="_blank">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test3.com" target="_blank">Test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test4.com" target="_blank">Test4</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test5.com" target="_blank">Test5</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test6.com" target="_blank">Test6</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test7.com" target="_blank">Test7</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.test8.com" target="_blank">Test8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution from the https://jsfiddle.net/2nh8aszc/7/

```
$("#ButtonSearch").click(function() {
  var textboxValue = $("#SearchLink").val().toLowerCase();



  $("#Slide5 ul li a").each(function(index,anchorTag) {
    // here is where I am stuck.. how do I compare textboxValue to each of the link's text and return a match?
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textboxValue.toLowerCase())!=-1){
         // Here Place code if keyword match
         $(this).parent('li').show();
    } else{
        //Here you can hide mismatch link. . . 
        $(this).parent('li').hide();
    }

  });

  if($('#Slide5 ul li').length == $('#Slide5 ul li:hidden').length){
    $("#Trig5").parent('h4').hide();
  } else {
    $("#Trig5").parent('h4').show();
  }


});
```

Comment: Anyway to hide the `h4` element if the value in the search box doesn't match any of the links under the `h4` element?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have updated my answer. Probably, It will be better solution for you to avoid extra conditional statement as well as code length.